# Most efficient way of finding out if someone has already published your idea?

Tags: reference-request, literature-search, publishability

As far as I see, there are two extreme methods of finding out whether someone has already published your idea:

1. Read everything that has ever been written, and then decide whether any of it corresponds to your idea. Advantage: You’ll be 100% sure that no one has written your idea before you try to publish it. Disadvantage: You’ll be dead before you’re done reading.
2. Search your memory for whether you’ve read something like it. Advantage: You’ll be done searching in a matter of seconds. Disadvantage: not very fault-proof at all.

Obviously, the optimal search method must lie somewhere between these extremes, and obviously the optimal approach will employ searching keywords.

**I am wondering what the optimal approach is, and whether there is a good guide on this.** I don’t want to waste many hours on sifting through other people’s writings if there is a more efficient way to do it. 
I’m sure that searching like this is a skill in and of itself. I’d like to become better at it.

Comment: Search for keywords?

Comment: @Keelan, thank you for your contribution. I hadn't thought of that! amazing.

Comment: That skill is called literature research, and consists of a few database skills plus common sense in deciding what to read from the results. I recommend reading rather more than less before getting "ideas".

Comment: I do not think that there is an optimal approach; how hard the problem is depends on many factors, e.g. how specific is your idea, how much you know about the topic/field, what resources are at your disposal, etc. The best thing you can do to save yourself time is to have a chat with somebody who is knowledgeable about the topic of your idea.

Comment: Commit your idea to paper and then apply for a patent - if they grant it ...

Comment: SolarMike, why so uncharitable?

Comment: @Programmer2134 there are some reasonable points made in the comment section, perhaps you could extend the question to explain why these obvious answers and not what your looking for? Or if they are what you are looking for, which bit of them you need guidance on.

Comment: @Programmer2134 I am not sure if you are being sincere or you are mocking?

Comment: @Paparazzi. I was being sincere. Some of the commenters it seems were not.

Comment: @Programmer2134 Be aware you are not coming off as sincere to all.  Other comments seem fine to me.

Comment: @Programmer2134 You're welcome. Point is you question sounds like you think you can become a scientist in some subject by *having an idea*. You can't. If you don't want to put in he work to become an expert yourself, you need a coworker who already is an expert.

Comment: @Programmer2134 You have voted to close this question as unclear. I think you would do the site a much greater service if you edited the question to improve it, rather than closing and abandoning it.

Answer (score 6):

Your first proposal is a little bit extreme. If you are working on a new sorting algorithm, for example, there is no need to read Tolstoy's *War and Peace,* or biographies on Benazir Bhutto.

My advisor suggested this strategy: Find a few papers strongly related to your research topic. Read through them, paying particular attention to the references. Then find all those references, and read through all of those articles, too.

As you do so, for every article you find that is closely related to your topic, look through the references there, and repeat the process.

Eventually, you'll reach a saturation point, where you'll find a good article, look through the references, and say to yourself, "I've already read all these." When you find yourself saying that routinely, then you're nearing the point where you've thoroughly researched the topic.

This method still isn't foolproof, but it's certainly more efficient than trying to "read everything that's ever been written" and a whole lot more reliable than "search your memory for whether you’ve read something like it."

Comment: yes, I'm aware of this approach. But it seems still very inefficient to me. The thing is, what if you have an idea for lets say, applying a statistical concept from your field to another field. It might be that the other field uses completely different terminology, so that you cant use a keyword search. Surely it would be very inefficient to first get to the point of a complete overview of that field before being able to publish your result. This is just ONE example, where it seems inefficient to first read an entire literature before being able to publish.

Comment: I think the example you've put in a comment below my answer would have been better included in your original question.

Comment: @Programmer2134 How about *talking* to the people from this other field? Maybe let them help you? Oh, you want all the fame for yourself. I'm sorry.